# Converting this.state to useEffect with Array in state

Tags: reactjs, constructor, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

newbie here, I'm missing sth when converting a class based compnent with constructor to function component with Hooks.

I have this.state which gets populated with an array I get from Firebase.

This works fine:

```
class MyList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ users: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {users.map(user => (
            <p>A mapped item</p>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't get the conversion right, been at it for hours and I must be having some conceptual problems:

```
function MyList() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      console.log(data);
      setUsers({ users: data })
    });
    }, [setUsers]);

    return (
      <>
        {users.map(user => (
            <p>A mapped item</p>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
```

Any help  would be much appreciated - newbie friendly please :)

Comment: Change `setUsers({ users: data })` to `setUsers(data)`. State in function components isn't an object (unless you want it to be)

Comment: Blimey, only took 2 hours out or my morning and it was as easy as that - thank you very much for correction and explanatrion: makes sense now! slaps himself in the face :D ->